# javascript <form name="item"> and getElementsByTagName() error

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot explain why is this happening:

> Uncaught TypeError: form_item.getElementsByTagName is not a function

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var form_item = document.forms['item'];
var buttons_item = form_item.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons_item.length; i++) {
 if (buttons_item[i].type === 'submit') {
  buttons_item[i].classList.add('someclass');
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="item" action="">
    <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

If I change the form's name, it works without any errors.

What is wrong? Why?
Thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have put complete HTML and JS code below - do you see it?

Comment: @dev101 (use a Stack Snippet)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, added stack snippet ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var form_item = document.querySelector('form[name=item]');
var buttons_item = form_item.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons_item.length; i++) {
 if (buttons_item[i].type === 'submit') {
  buttons_item[i].classList.add('someclass');
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="item" action="">
 <button type="submit">BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

You can try it inside your browser's console type and send those commands:

```
document.forms["item"]
```

-

```
document.forms.item
```

Those commands means the same thing and ask for the document.forms.item() function.

---

And that's the workaround you need:

```
document.querySelector('form[name=item]');
```

Comment: Thanks Marco! The edited version solved the problem! Accepted as an answer.

Comment: Yes sorry i  made a mistake while copying the solution ahaha

Comment: No problem! Spent hours on this :)

Comment: @dev101: If you don't need `form_item` for something later, you can just use `var buttons_item = document.querySelectorAll('form[name=item] button');`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`document.forms.item` is a function that returns a form.

Your name conflicts with that.

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately, this is coded inside CMS, is there a workaround - possibly without naming the form? :(

Comment: Use `getElementsByName()`

Comment: I know this is the right answer. I just wish I could find a spec to back it up. A lot of these old legacy accessors got documented, and I thought this was one of them, but I can't find `document.forms` anywhere...

Comment: I still cannot make it work, replacing it with getElementsByName() still shows the same error. Update: Marco's answer above solved it!

Answer (score 1):

The querySelector in JavaScript works like what you may know in JQuery selctors.

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): `Document.querySelector()` Returns the first Element within the document (using depth-first
>   pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in
>   document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of
>   amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

For your HTML markup you could use just use `[name='item'`:

```js
var form_item = document.querySelector('[name=item]');
var buttons_item = form_item.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons_item.length; i++) {
  if (buttons_item[i].type === 'submit') {
    buttons_item[i].classList.add('someclass');
  }
}
```

```css
.someclass {
  background: #6600ff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form name="item" action="">
  <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

---

The snippet above works as expected, but here is the question, why the `item` name was not working by the way you were going to access that!?

Because the `item` is a function for `doctument.forms`

> [W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp): `item(index)` Returns the  element from the collection with the
>   specified index (starts at 0).

You can easily try it, open your web developer console (like Chrome DevTools) and type in: `document.forms.item(0)`, you will get the first form of the document

---

By the way, this function also can be helpful to understanding better how really forms work

```js
function getFormByName(theName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        var form_item = document.forms.item(i);
        if (form_item.name == theName) {
            return form_item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var form_item = getFormByName('item');
if (form_item) {
    var buttons_item = form_item.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons_item.length; i++) {
        if (buttons_item[i].type === 'submit') {
            buttons_item[i].classList.add('someclass');
        }

    }
}
```

```css
.someclass{
   background:gold;
   color:red;
   border:none;
}
```

```html
<form name="item" action="">
  <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks M98! Upvoted because of your clear efforts to explain it :)

Comment: @dev101 Thanks for your feedback, I'm glad the answer seems helpful